# Where is the downed jumbo jet?

Tags: dead-island

In one of the cut scenes early on, it showed a jumbo jet coming in for an emergency landing on the island, where did it land?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's found in the jungle during Act 3, after the city. It's in the bottom left corner of your map.

Comment: So I'm in act 2 and I talked to a woman in the lighthouse and she told me to go find the jet (offering a purple weapon as a reward), is that possible at this point?

Comment: No it's not just yet, it's one of those quests that you have to keep until later.

Answer (score 0):

The plane is only accessible in Act 3, in the bottom left corner of your map. The biggest clue is when she says "Jungle" because you dont get to the jungle until act 3, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

When you reach Act 3, you relocate to the jungle and the quest called "Nighthawk" will appear in your log. Track this quest and it will show you where the plane is on the map.